# Adding new server to existing Mongo Replica Set

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I inherited a MongoDB replica set with three 4.4 servers running on three Windows Server 2016 hosts. There's a primary, secondary, and an arbiter and I want to add another server in a different location. Is there a way to do this without having to shut down the current servers? Can I manually copy the data files over before the server add without shutting down the primary if no data is being read/written to the db? I expected to see the settings for primary/secondary/etc in the config files but am not.

Here's the config file for the primary:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\data
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: false
  path:  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true


#processManagement:

security:
  keyFile: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\keyfile.txt
  transitionToAuth: true

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: be-rs1
  enableMajorityReadConcern: false

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

And the one for the secondary:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\data
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\log\mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true


#processManagement:

security:
  keyFile: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\keyfile.txt
  #transitionToAuth: true

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: be-rs1
  enableMajorityReadConcern: false

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: Does the ["_Add Members to a Replica Set_"](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/expand-replica-set/) documentation answer your question?

Comment: It doesn't as it doesn't go into details about primary being shut down, config files vs cmd line etc. It's pretty sparse in terms of information.

Comment: Just a note, I would not put logging and/or application data in `C:\Program Files\...` Better create a dedicated directory for them. You may run into problems regarding backup or file permissions. And you should enclose the path by quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer here is that you don't need to shutdown or manually move any data.  Per the [instructions documented here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/expand-replica-set/#add-a-member-to-an-existing-replica-set), the two main steps that you need to take are:

1. Start the new `mongod` process (with appropriate configuration) on the new server.
2. Run the `rs.add()` command against the `PRIMARY` of the existing replica set.

MongoDB will then take care of the rest, including [initial syncing the data](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/core/replica-set-sync/#initial-sync) to the new server.

With respect to part `1` and config files in general, you can probably just copy the existing config files assuming that the new server is arranged the same way in terms of directories and the keyfile etc.

A couple of additional items that may be worth noting based on the phrasing in the question:

- Generally you want to avoid having a replica set that has an even number of voting members, see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/#deploy-an-odd-number-of-members). Ideally you would subsequently remove the Arbiter from the replica set.
- "*I expected to see the settings for primary/secondary/etc in the config files*" - data bearing members are not manually specified as `PRIMARY` or `SECONDARY`. This can be influenced by setting priorities, but overall MongoDB handles this internally as part of its high availability functionality, see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-elections/) for some details.

Comment: The documentation here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/expand-replica-set/ says to copy the data manually in order to speed things up. We don't have a ton of time to do the add over the weekend so I'm hoping to do it in the quickest way possible. 

The link discusses the oplog window which is what got me thinking of shutting the set down for the data copy. And yeah we're planning on removing the arbiter after we have an odd number of members, thanks!